# Hometown synonym for work city?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like the word hometown is used to refer to the place you are originally from, what is the word for the place you're working? Is `worktown` a legit word?

Comment: Is workplace the answer?

Comment: What did you find in the dictionary for worktown and workplace?

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. Worktown doesn't exist in dictionary. Workplace refers to "a person's place of employment."